# How to redirect output of command to a file and in parallel pipe to other command?

Tags: bash

I would like to save the output of a command as a file but also in parallel pipe it to another command without having to write the same string of code twice.

Here an example:

```
ls -1 > output.txt
ls -1 | wc -l
```

I would like to circumvent writing `ls -1` twice.

This obviously does not work:

```
ls -1 > output.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))

```
ls | tee output.txt | wc -l
```